# Center div content with Bootstrap (center-block)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I center the content of div with center-block??

The following example does not work:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="center-block">
            <input id="user_registrate" type="submit" value="Registrate" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jd93fL1x/2/

And this one works:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
            <input id="user_registrate" type="submit" value="Registrate" class="btn btn-success center-block" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jd93fL1x/3/

I want two buttons centered, that is why I want the div with the center-block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class `center-block` applies the center to the element itself, not to the content; in this case you can use the class `text-center` on the container and since the input has the class `btn` making it inline-block, that will work:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <input id="user_registrate" type="submit" value="Registrate" class="btn btn-success" />
    <input id="user_registrate" type="submit" value="Registrate" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
```

#### [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd93fL1x/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-align:center` on the div:

```
.center-block {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jd93fL1x/5/)**

(or use the selector `.form-group > div` instead of `.center-block` if you're not using that class for anything)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply put text-align:center

```
<div class="form-group">
<div style="text-align:center">
        <input id="user_registrate" type="submit" value="Registrate" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
```